# Flask: Why the session expire so quick?

Tags: python, session, flask

I am writing a site by using python+flask
when using the session, i set the session just like the following code:

```
@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(days=5)
```

but after few minutes the session was cleared, i want to know the reason, anyone who can help me ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are going for here, but put the app config stuff first, not inside a request handler

Comment: What are you trying to do?